# How to use Google Cloud Debugger on Cloud Run with Django

Tags: google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Debugger on Cloud Run with Django. I red this document.

https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/python

### What I did.

1. I turned on Debugger in google cloud.
2. Install google-python-cloud-debugger.
3. I created source-context.json same directory with models.py
4. I add this code in manage.py

```
try:
      import googleclouddebugger
      googleclouddebugger.enable()

    except ImportError:
      pass
```

I update container of Google Cloud Run. How ever I cant find any application in [Debugger](https://console.cloud.google.com/debug)

I imported my source code from GitHub. I can see my code in Debugger. However, I couldn't check break point in Debugger page.

How to debug Django on Clod Run? Please help me.

### Update

I did this 2 step.

1. Add logger `Cloud Debugger Agent` rights to the service account from [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=proartapi).
2. Connect GitHub repository with Google Cloud Source

Cloud Debugger works on local environment. However it doesn't work in Cloud Run.

This picture has only local application. I can't find Cloud Run application.
[image]

This is my yaml file. (I'm using Cloud Run as full managed mode)

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my_app
  namespace: '135253772466'
  selfLink: /apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/135253772466/services/my_app
  uid: 61b4ac55-4aab-4d33-801d-d21b0d116ea4
  resourceVersion: AAWmjubgiTg
  generation: 176
  creationTimestamp: '2020-04-14T12:38:39.484473Z'
  labels:
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: asia-northeast1
  annotations:
    run.googleapis.com/client-name: gcloud
    serving.knative.dev/creator: 135253772466@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
    serving.knative.dev/lastModifier: 135253772466@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
    client.knative.dev/user-image: gcr.io/my_project/my_app
    run.googleapis.com/client-version: 291.0.0
spec:
  traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my_app-00176-wud
      annotations:
        run.googleapis.com/client-name: gcloud
        client.knative.dev/user-image: gcr.io/my_project/my_app
        run.googleapis.com/client-version: 291.0.0
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '1000'
    spec:
      timeoutSeconds: 900
      serviceAccountName: 135253772466-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      containerConcurrency: 80
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/my_project/my_app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: CLOUD_RUN_HOST
          value: my_app-u3ljntrlma-an.a.run.app
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 2048Mi
status:
  conditions:
  - type: Ready
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-26T15:39:32.595Z'
  - type: ConfigurationsReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-26T15:39:25.640Z'
  - type: RoutesReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-26T15:39:32.595Z'
  observedGeneration: 176
  traffic:
  - revisionName: my_app-00176-wud
    percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
  latestReadyRevisionName: my_app-00176-wud
  latestCreatedRevisionName: my_app-00176-wud
  address:
    url: https://my_app-u3ljntrlma-an.a.run.app
  url: https://my_app-u3ljntrlma-an.a.run.app
```

Comment: Can you provide your yaml and configuration files?

Comment: Yes,I can. I added my yaml file.

Comment: Did you figure out?

Comment: It's not yet...